# Help My Mango Tree Is Dying!

Tags: trees, diagnosis, fruit-trees, mango

My sapling was doing amazing throughout the summer and as it grew I changed its pot and added more dirt. It was doing good but then as September hit the leaves started to turn yellow and I thought it was because it was getting to much water so I stopped watering it so much but nothing changed. It continued to loose leaves and I'm very worried. I really want this tree to grow. Can anyone help me since this is my first time growing a tree here in South Florida.

Comment: A picture would help